# How to properly escape text inside <option> tag?

Tags: html, escaping, html-select

When inserting untrusted text into an HTML document, there are certain special characters you must escape (e.g. <, &, ", etc.). (" for quoted attributes). For example:

```
<div>Some tags are <b> and <div></div>
```

becomes:

```
<div>Some tags are &lt;b&gt; and &lt;div&gt;</div>
```

(One can debate the need for &gt; but that's not relevant here.)

That's great but what about inside an option tag?  If I want the text to be "</option>", how do I do it?

This does not work:

```
<option>&lt;&sol;option&gt;</option>
```

What I find is that the HTML character entities, (&lt;,&gt;, etc.) are dropped.  I've tried both Chrome and Firefox.  I assume this is related to the fact that the option tag cannot contain nested tags.  Google has failed me on this one.  :(

And a related question:  Since <option> has special escaping behavior as shown above, and we know <script> has its own behavior.  Is there a complete list somewhere of all the HTML tags that have special escaping behavior and what there rules are?

Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to make option like `<option></option></option>` ? that's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, as demonstrated in the below snippet, you can escape HTML entities inside the `<option>` tag perfectly fine (tested on Firefox, Chrome & Safari).

So you are able to have the text `</option>` inside an option tag. This is done using the HTML entities that represent the `<` and `>` characters

Essentially it is the same as having:

```
<option></option></option>
```

Although the middle `</option>` is not treated as a closing tag, but rather it is shown that way in the browser

As a side note, the only limitation using `<option>` tags when escaping characters lays in the `:before` and `:after` CSS pseudo elements. [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) suggests that you cannot prepend/append content to the `<option>` tag using these pseudo elements. Although for some reason, in Firefox 48 this does infact work

```css
#css-option:before {
  content: "any text";
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>&lt;/option&gt;</option>
  <option>&#60;/option&#62;</option>
  <option>&lt;&sol;option&gt;</option>
  <option id="css-option"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: That worked for me.  I must have a bug somewhere else that is somehow doing this evil to me.  Maybe that means I should take a break and sleep well tonight.  :)